# The Mystery Word

Tags: cipher, crosswords

**STEPS FOR SOLVING (READ FIRST):**

First, review the crossword puzzle and its hints.
Next, solve each space of the crossword puzzle **except** for A10. When you are done solving the rest of the crossword puzzle, read the hints for A10 and solve it.

A **final** solution to this problem **must** include the solved crossword puzzle, an explanation of the ciphers used in the hints, and **how A10 is solved.**

**NOTE: Partial solutions are accepted.**

**Crossword Puzzle:**

[image: crossword puzzle]

**Clues:**

```
A1: The color of tenff as an nqwrpgvir.
D2: Completely lost in the middle of _______.
D3: Name meaning "rohe, nam fo cuogear."
D4: A type of fish, but also a Bo is-acunbllameasasr.
A5: Lonely child without parsetn.
A6: A caluvn rmiaald.
D7: Jvualtwabvbz and zjvyumbs.
A8: The Ch_____ Re___li_ of Ru___a.
A9: One who .- -... .- -. -.. --- -. ... / .- -... .--- ..- .-. . ...
A10: [SEE BELOW]
```

**Clues for A10:**

1:

> Only solve A10 once you have solved the other clues.

2:

> All of the previous answers have one other pair except for one. The pair of that one is the answer to this one.

Comment: Slow down, tiger.  You give clues as if they are vitamin.  Yum.

Comment: Lol. I'll delete that last hint. Those hints are more like "clues"; I worded it wrong.

Comment: Oh wow, i recognize what i don't when i see it.  Was gonna solve this but can't.

Comment: A8 is obvious.  A good crossword has an obvious bite and then another that doesn't make sense until it does.

Comment: You don't need to give spoilered hints immediately on puzzle release!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The clues, decoded, and their answers:

> [image: clues with answers]
>
>  (Some issues with the clues: "greeny" isn't an adverb, and two clues commit "The Error That Cannot Be Named", with the answer directly given in the clue.)

A10 is solved by

> noticing that all the answers are rot13 pairs of other answers:
>
>  `NOWHERE - ABJURER`
>  `GREENY - TERRAL`
>  `SNEERY - FYRREL`
>  `ORPHAN - BECUNA`
>
>  The remaining answer is `CHECHEN`, which rot13s to `PURPURA`.

Comment: rot(12), not rot(13):
Etaaf, U ime ea oxaeq! Ftq qddade uz ftue bgllxq udwqp yq, zaf azxk "sdqqzk" ngf mxea geuzs "otqotqz" uz ftq oxgq zmyq itqz "Otqotzkm" rufe rmd nqffqd. Ftq daf-13 oazrudyqp ftue me ftq eaxgfuaz U nqxuqhq.

Mxea, eqhqz paiz ue daf(eqhqz), mzp ragd paiz ue mzaftqd mzmsdmy rad Nmxqa-oxmee egnymduzq.

Comment: Changed the "greeny" hint slightly, thanks for solving the puzzle!